# How to use Bottom Bar together with SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a sprite kit project and was trying to add a bottom bar to it. However, after selecting the "opaque toolbar":

`Game View Controller > Attribute Inspector > Simulated Metrics > Bottom Bar > Opaque toolbar`

While the toolbar does appear in `Main.Storyboard`, it does not show up in the simulator.

Whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a "Simulated Metrics", this will only add a bar in the Storyboard (it just helps the developer to see graphically how it should show in the real device, and helps with constraints).

You need to add a `UITabBarController` in the storyboard. (you can drag and drop and you will see how it works)

[image]